# JavaFX TabPane: How to set the selected tab

Tags: java, tabs, selecteditem, javafx-2

I have a Java Desktop Application with JavaFX 2 in it and in my FX I've got a TabPane. I want to set the default tab. In other words I want to set a tab as selected. I found that there are multiple ways to find out which tab is selected and I found `setSelectionModel()` but I can't figure out how to use it.

```
TabPane tabPane = new TabPane();

Tab tab0 = new Tab("blue");
tab.setContent(new Rectangle(200,200, Color.BLUE));

Tab tab1 = new Tab("green");
tab.setContent(new Rectangle(200,200, Color.GREEN));

tabPane.getTabs().addAll(tab0, tab1);
```

Answer (score 118, accepted):

The `SelectionModel`is the right approach. You can get the default from your `TabPane` or assign your own implementation by using `setSelectionModel(...)`. The default model should be good enough for the beginning.

```
SingleSelectionModel<Tab> selectionModel = tabPane.getSelectionModel();
```

Once you stored it in some local variable, you have different options to select a tab.

```
selectionModel.select(tab); //select by object
selectionModel.select(1); //select by index starting with 0
selectionModel.clearSelection(); //clear your selection
```

If you try to select a non existing tab, nothing will happen.

Answer (score 37):

To simplify the above mentioned approach:

```
myTabPane.getSelectionModel().select(myTab);
```

Comment: It really helps.

Answer (score 1):

To continue with Menai's answer heres how to refocus the opened tab/TabPane.

```
SingleSelectionModel<Tab> selectionModel = TabPane.getSelectionModel();
if(!Tabpane.getTabs().contains(tabName)) {
   TabPane.getTabs().add(tabName);
   selectionModel.select(tabPane);
} else {
   selectionModel.select(tabPane); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
TabPane tabPane = new TabPane();

tabPane.getSelectionModel().select(); //Select Tab
tabPane.getSelectionModel().select(); //Select tab index
tabPane.getSelectionModel().selectLast();
tabPane.getSelectionModel().selectFirst();
tabPane.getSelectionModel().selectNext();
tabPane.getSelectionModel().selectPrevious();
tabPane.getSelectionModel().clearSelection(); //Select Tab
tabPane.getSelectionModel().clearSelection(); //Select tab index
```

Answer (score -1):

If you work with **statique** tabs ,i mean your TabPane has statique number of tabs ,you can select your tab by this way :

```
 SingleSelectionModel<Tab> selectionModel = TabPane.getSelectionModel();

        selectionModel.select(tabName);
```

If you work with **dynamique** tabs ,i mean your TabPane has dynamique number of tabs (add and remove tabs) ,you can select your tab by this way :

```
        if (!TabPane.getTabs().contains(tabName)) {

        TabPane.getTabs().add(tabName);

    }
    SingleSelectionModel<Tab> selectionModel = TabPane.getSelectionModel();

    selectionModel.select(tabPane);
```